# Rails 3 Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does rails 3 natively support foreign key constraints (Without a plugin or 3rd party gem)?

If it doesn't what is the best way to validate foreign key constraints?

Comment: Are you referring to SQL foreign keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. For Rails 3, you can use the ["ValidatesExistence"](https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence) gem.

Answer (score 0):

Nop. But you can use [Foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner). In addition you can use [Immigrant](https://github.com/jenseng/immigrant) to generate a migration that includes all missing foreign keys.